# Error: The project hits has not enabled BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to export data from GA using BigQuery and the Query failed.

I use this functions:

- `FLATTEN`
- `TABLE_DATA_RANGE`

  Because I need data from hits.

Can anyone help me about this Error?

Error:

> The project hits has not enabled BigQuery

Now, the error is other: Field CampaignGrouping not found:

```
SELECT
a.hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 AS CampaignGrouping,
a.customDimensions.value AS member_PK,
'Web' AS Canal,
'ES' AS country_id,
count(a.hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2) AS VistasUnicas
FROM FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
  (SELECT
  hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2,
  hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2,
  customDimensions.value  
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([###.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-04-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-04-30'))), 
  hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2), customDimensions.value
  )a
WHERE hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2<>'(not set)' AND customDimensions.value<>'null' AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 5 ASC
```

Comment: What do you mean you are trying to export data from GA to BQ? Are you using the ga_sessions tables? And what query did you run? Can you post it here for us?

Comment: Please edit your question with the query you are running. Probably there's some mistake there. Also, it would be nice if you could explain us what you want to analyze with this query ;)

Comment: Okey, Done it!!

Comment: Also, do you have to use legacy sql? The Standard version is the recommended approach to work in BQ

Comment: But using the Standard version, don't run the query... i'm novice at the Sql programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your problem in [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) is much easier than in Legacy.

This query might help you on computing this:

```
SELECT
  hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 CampaignGrouping,
  custd.value member_PK,
  'Web' Canal,
  'ES' AS country_id,
  SUM(hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2) VistasUnicas
FROM
  `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(customdimensions) custd,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-05-06')
  and hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2<>'(not set)'
  AND custd.value<>'null'
  AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  1, 2
ORDER BY 5 ASC
```

You just need to [enable it](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) and it's already ready to run.

As you said you are learning SQL, it's highly recommended that you start by learning the Standard version instead of the Legacy one as it's more stable and offers several different techniques to better assist you on your analyzes.

Comment: Thank you so much Will!! ;)

Now, if i need to make a union from all datasets with the same information than the query i'm using, how i can do?

Comment: Other question: Now i'm contrasting the info with GA, and is not equal. And i have problem with the dates, because are range of days on i haven't data according BigQuery.

Can you explain me how works the functions when declarates the time/dates?

Comment: Hi @HéctorIbáñez, I'm afraid I didn't quite understand. By union all datasets you mean how to get all ga_sessions tables in the dataset? Also, what differences are you observing from G.A? Is it something related to dates?

Comment: Hi @Will , i'm trying to extract all the info that is at query from a date range. Then concatenate this info with the same info but from other dataset.
I have 12 datasets but the info is the same, only change the country and channel,